# JQUERY Validate Plugin Error - Hide the field

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, field, hidden

I'm using this plugin to validate some html fields.

But after the second click on the "btnGravar" these fields get hidden, just disappear with "display:none" ...

Someone knows why ?

[SOURCE CODE](http://pastebin.com/kcpeygYx)

Comment: can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ of relevant code and paste the link here

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change the type of "btnGravar" to submit, and do not put any kind of event handling on click of this button, then your form will be automatically checked by jQuery until it is validated completely.
Instead of this :

```
    <input type="button" id="btnGravar" value="Gravar"/>
```

Use this:

```
    <input type="submit" id="btnGravar" value="Gravar"/>
```